# As will be discussed later in this comment

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

**As will be discussed** in more detail in the next section, all exchange rate regimes offer benefits as well as costs.

As common as this structure is, I am having some trouble to figure out its syntax. Why is the omission of subject allowed in this clause? Is it a case of elision?

I know that saying "as **it** will be discussed..." would have a different meaning. Yet I would like to know what is the explanation for the question I posted.

Comment: Where's an omission?

Comment: I cannot see the subject in this clause: _As will be discussed in more detail in the next section_

Comment: You may need to invert the clauses to see the structure: "All exchange rate regimes offer benefits as well as costs, as will be discussed in more detail in the next section." Does that parse?

Comment: Yes, I guess I'm messed up. I was trying to understand grammar at the clause level, not sentence.

Answer (score 1):

AS is a subordinating conjuction with the adverbial sense " in the manner":
¶ This is as it should be.(here subordinate clause beginning with "as" is a noun clause functioning as complement to "this"
¶¶ in the given example/As will be discussed.......... next section/it is an adverbial phrase(not a clause) placed before the main clause with a "," as usual modifying the verb'offer'.AS introduces adverb clauses & phrases. Here also--As (it) will be discussed..... this "impersonal IT" is omitted to make it participle phrase by construction and adverbial in function.

If you just read "As will be ........section" with out the main clause, it will be a run-on sentence.

Comment: You need help in formatting.